# Is "recyclist" a word?

Tags: suffixes, is-it-a-word, derivational-morphology, derivation

If you are a person who avidly recycles, are you a recyclist?

Comment: I corrected your title, just for visual reasons.

Comment: If your intent was referring to "one who recycles" or someone who cares about the environment, he or she would be called an environmentalist, not a recyclist.

Comment: No, but that is an awesome word for a driver of used bicycles.  C.f. recyclista, an _avid_ driver of used bicycles.

Comment: @Neil: Environmentalists care about the environment, I just like to turn old things into new things. So I am a self proclaimed  Recyclist. @elliot42: I also like used bicycles ;P

Comment: Well then you are a recycler, not a recyclist.  I think environmentalist encompasses every aspect regarding helping the environment, including recycling.

Comment: I don't think its possible to say whether or not "recyclist" is a word, as _word_ [is not sufficiently well defined](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3342)

Comment: If a "racist" is someone who believes a particular race is superior, a "recyclist" is someone who believes a recycler is superior (or maybe that certain trash is superior to other trash).

Comment: Isn't a "recyclist" someone who does the TdF twice?

Comment: Wouldn't a lover of recycling be a "recycliphil"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from deliberately quirky usage, I think not. You'd be a **recycler**.

Things can always change, but I don't think there's really a case for accepting **recyclist** as a valid English word just yet.

Comment: But a recycler would be the person/company who takes the material and recycles it (into a new product). In modern use there probably needs to be a term for somebody who takes stuff to be recycled

Comment: In the modern world we need the word **recyclist** about as much as we need the word **breather**. Anyone who doesn't do these things is headed for an evolutionary dead-end.

Comment: You could also say you don't need "environmentalist" for the same reason ;-) Of course symmetry says that we should need a word "environmentaler" for somebody who makes the environment

Comment: @Martin The word "recycle" itself doesn't distinguish between putting something in a blue bin and actually melting down (or whatever) and re-using it, either.

Comment: @Matthew - that's why we need "recyclist"

Comment: @Martin That's why we need context, modifiers, and/or direct explanation :P I don't think we need a word for every possible subdivision of meaning.

Comment: @Martin Beckett: I think if we were told "John is a recycler", most of us wouldn't assume he worked in the recycling business, even if we'd never come across the usage before. But if I were checking that statement with John, I'd ask him *Do you recycle*?, not *Are you a recyclist*?

Comment: "I recycle.  He recycles.  They recycle."  Problem solved.

Comment: @Mike not quite. "ACME corp recycles paper" does this mean ACME corp don't put printer output in the trash or does it mean ACME corp process paper for recycling?

Comment: @Martin: Anything big enough to be a 'corp' would probably bring down the attentions of the authorities if they didn't recycle paper used internally, so my money is on paper recycling being Acme's core business.

Answer (score 2):

[image: recycler vs. recyclist vs. recyclers vs recyclists]

It doesn't even show in [the NGram Viewer](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=recycler,recyclist,recyclers,%20recyclists&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=0) but [there's at least 77 books that mention "recyclist"](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&tbo=1&q=recyclist&btnG=Search%20Books)

Answer (score 1):

The OED (Oxford English Dictionary) classifies it as *rare* (and maybe it means something else too, but I'm not sure from the definition given), while the OALD and the NOAD don't even mention it.

The word you're looking for is **recycler**, which doesn't appear in the OALD, but on the NOAD it's given as a derivative word from Recycle and on the OED "*One who or that which recycles (waste products, etc.).*"

Comment: Perhaps you're looking at the 1989 definition? The 2009 definition drops the *rare*.

Answer (score 1):

The third edition of the *Oxford English Dictionary* ("fully updated"online, March 2016) has the following definition for

**recyclist**

> An advocate of the recycling of waste products; a recycler.

and includes two usage examples not included in previous versions of the entry for this word,  namely

> 1986   *Peace News* 23 May 17/1,   I recommend all people who are tree lovers, recyclists and on low incomes to read friends' copies, buy copies collectively or go to the library.
>
> 1998   *N.Y. Times* 20 Sept. 26   Tap-water enthusiasts and recyclists worried that plastic containers will clog landfills.

The OED has also dropped the description *rare* for this word.

So, yes, it's a word, and it's a synonym for *recycler*. Not that we needed the OED to verify this.